# Как считывать данные гироскопа в питон код

Tags: python

У меня есть Dualshok 4 v2 подключён к ПК по блютузу и программу DS4Windwos
Я хочу играть в разные игры используя Геймпад в качестве руля, а именно его гироскоп
Для начало мне нужно хотя бы что бы выводились данные гироскопа в консоль
Я пробовал через PyGame Но он выводит данные стиков
Код который я использовал

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()

pygame.joystick.init()

joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()


joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
joystick.init()

try:
    while True:
        pygame.event.pump()
        
        gyro_x = joystick.get_axis(3)
        gyro_y = joystick.get_axis(4)
        gyro_z = joystick.get_axis(5)

        print(f"Gyro X: {gyro_x}, Gyro Y: {gyro_y}, Gyro Z: {gyro_z}")
        time.sleep(0.1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Вот какая-то библиотека https://github.com/anubisankh/dualshock4-python.

Comment: там по usb потключение